# Beautiful inequality based on an Idea from Michael Rozenberg

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This is an inequality based on an idea from Michael Rozenberg in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602035/for-abc-1-prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fracaa111-leq-frac32). This is the following:

Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers with $xyz=1$ then we have:

$$\frac{0.5\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(f(x))}+\frac{0.5\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(f(z))}+\frac{0.5\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(f(y))}\leq 1.5$$

With $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x^{11}+1}$.

Sincerely, I have no idea to prove this because this is more difficult than the original one.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your inequality is inspired by one of Michael Rozenberg's answers, you can give a link to it in your question to provide more context.

Comment: More difficult than what? – Can you provide *any* argument why this should be true (apart from the fact that it is holds for $x=y=z=1$)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to precised what it was . This is this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602035/for-abc-1-prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fracaa111-leq-frac32 .

Comment: @FatsWallers I've added this directly in your question.

Comment: What is the meaning of the coefficient $0.5$?

Comment: Maybe this will help: the minimal value of $\Gamma (f(x))\Gamma (f(1/x)))$ is $\pi$

Comment: Hint is ready...

Comment: The final edition is ready.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FINAL EDITION $08.03.18$

---

**FUNCTIONS**

At first, let us consider [the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%2F(t%5E11%2B1))
$$f(t)=\dfrac{t}{t^{11} + 1},\quad t\in[0, \infty).$$
Easy to see that
$$f(0) = f(\infty) = 0$$
and
$$\dfrac{df}{dt} = \dfrac{1 - 10 t^{11}}{(t^{11} + 1)^2}.$$
So $f(t)$ is unimodal in the interval $[0, \infty),$ with the maximum 
$$f'(t_m) = 0,\quad t_m = \dfrac1{\sqrt[11]{10}} \approx 0.81113,\quad f_m = f(t_m) = \dfrac1{11}10^{10/11}\approx 0.73739.\tag1$$
This means that the actual range of values of the gamma function is $(0,f_m),$
where the terms increases monotonically and
$$g_m = \dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma(f_m)} \approx 1.4264505975\dots\tag2$$

Also note that
$$f(1) = \dfrac 12,\quad \Gamma\left(\dfrac12\right) = \sqrt\pi.$$

This means that the issue inequality becomes exact equality when 
$$x = y = z = 1,\quad f(x)= \dfrac12.$$
In the same time, if $t>1,$ then $f(t) < \dfrac12.$

Thus, at least one of values $x,\ y,\ z$ belongs to the interval $(0, 1].$

These are the reasons to consider [the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%20pi%2FGamma(1%2F2%2Bt))
$$v(t) = \dfrac {\sqrt\pi}{\Gamma\left(t+\dfrac12\right)}\tag3$$
for the values $t+\dfrac12 \in [0,\ f_m],$ where it increases monotonically.

Then, one can obtain the Taylor series in the form of
$$v(t) = 1 + v_1t + v_2t^2 + v_3t^3 + v_4t^2 +\dots,\tag4$$
where
\begin{aligned}
&v_1 = -\psi^{(0)}\left(\dfrac12\right) = \gamma + \log 4 \approx1.9635100260\dots,\\
&v_2 = -\dfrac14(\pi^2 - 2v_1^2) = -\dfrac14(p - 2\pi^2) \approx 0.53971 52891\dots,\\
&v_3 = -\dfrac1{12}(3\pi^2v_1 - 2v_1^3 - 28\zeta(3)) = -\dfrac1{12}(pv_1-28\zeta(3))\approx -0.7782905521\dots,\\[4pt]
&v_4 = \dfrac1{96}(4v_1^4 - 12\pi^2v_1^2 + 224\zeta(3)v_1)\\[4pt]
&\quad = \dfrac1{96}(p^2 - 10\pi^2 - 8\cdot28\zeta(3)v_1)\approx 0.3555284642\dots,\\
&\gamma \approx 0.5772156649\dots \text{(Euler gamma constant)},\\[4pt]
&p = 3\pi^2 - 2v_1^2 \approx 21.8980699586\dots,\\[4pt]
&28\zeta(3) = 33.6575932884\dots.
\end{aligned}
[Easy to see that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5Csqrt+pi%2Fgamma(t)+%3D+1%2B(eulergamma+%2B+log4)(2t-1)%2F2,+t%5Cin(0,+0.74))
$$v(t) \le 1 + v_1\left(t-\dfrac12\right)\tag5$$

Taking in account [the proof of Michael Rozenberg inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602035/for-abc-1-prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fracaa111-leq-frac32/2682250#2682250)
$$f(x) + f(y) + f(z) \le \dfrac32\quad \text{ if } (x,y,z)\in(0,\infty)^3 \wedge xyz = 1,$$

one can write:
$$v(f(x)) + v(f(y)) + v(f(z)) - 3 \le v_1\left(f(x) -\dfrac12 + f(y) -\dfrac12 + f(z) -\dfrac12\right) \le 0,$$

$$\boxed{v(f(x)) + v(f(y)) + v(f(z)) \le 3.} $$

Comment: I think it's very interesting because you have separated the problem in another wich is simpler . Ps : at the end it's not $xyz=1$ ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the step (4) -> (5)? Unless I made an error, $h(1) \approx 0.94$, so that for $x=y=z=1$ $h(x)+h(y)+h(z) \approx 2.82$, which is *larger* than $3/\sqrt \pi \approx 1.69$.

Comment: @MartinR yes I remark that to .In fact without any numerical argument there is a strict inequality follow by a larger one . So there is a problem...

Comment: Indeed, the original inequality is sharp, so any solution with strict inequalities *cannot* be correct.

Comment: @MartinR This is only idea, not  the final edition. The approximation will be changed. Thanks, you are right.

Comment: There is so many problems that...First you can invoke a more general concept than the unimodality like the quasiconvexity and use a Jensen like formula . Secondly you can't cut the Taylor series it involves the last message of MartinR . Finally I think you can't solve this problem without separate the problem in different cases . However good luck !

Comment: @FatsWallers I can fix all the problems, using more hard way. I'm doing that now, but I would not update the answer permanently.

Comment: I trust in you man thanks for your interest !

Comment: @FatsWallers The question is interesting. And this is a challenge for me.

Comment: @MartinR And now?