# Inequality $\frac{x}{x^{10}+1}+\frac{y}{y^{10}+1}+\frac{z}{z^{10}+1}\leq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I try to prove this :

> Let $x,y,z>0$ such that $xyz=1$ then we have :
>   $$\frac{x}{x^{10}+1}+\frac{y}{y^{10}+1}+\frac{z}{z^{10}+1}\leq \frac{3}{2}$$

You can follow my proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602035/for-abc-1-prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fracaa111-leq-frac32).It works too but I have some doubt for the end so my real question is :

> How to prove that the maximum of the function below is $1.5$ :
>   $$f(x)=\frac{2x^9}{x^{10}+1}+\frac{x^2}{x^{20}+1}$$

Thanks for your interest .

Comment: Do you use the second yellow box statement in your proof of the main inequaity of the post? If so how to know your proof "works"?

Comment: So your real question is whether your own answer in the other thread is correct, and if not, how to fix it?