We know that xyz=1. Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{1+x^4} \leq \frac{3}{2}$
We know that xyz=1. Show that $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{1+x^4} \leq \frac{3}{2}$
I thought of using the linear method but got to nothing useful. 1 should be a double root of the equation $\frac{x}{1+x^4}\leq ax+b$.
Also I thought of writing $\frac{x}{1+x^4}= \frac{x}{x(yz+x^3)}= \frac{1}{yz+x^3}$.

Just my intuition: using $\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^4} \leq \dfrac 1 2$ and considering the upper limit of $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1}{1+x^4}$ can help.

Similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600732/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2602035/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3621922/42969

@RDK But how do you use that inequality. Also I was able to show that L-H-S $\leq \frac{1}{2}( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} )$

Sorry about the confusing intuition; see my answer below. ;)

Similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602035/prove-that-sum-limits-cyc-fracaa111-leq-frac32-for-a-b-c-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

This question is similar to: Prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^{11}+1}\leq\frac{3}{2}$ for $a, b, c > 0$ with $abc = 1$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sorry about the confusing intuition; the intuition above just gives another complicated problem. I’ll suggest another proof. (Little bit dirty)
\begin{align}
& \text{Claim. } \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1}{x^3+2} \leq 1. \\
\text{pf. }& \text{Let. } x^3 = \dfrac a b, y^3 = \dfrac b c, z^3 = \dfrac c a. (\because x^3y^3z^3=1.) \\
\Rightarrow \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {1}{x^3+2} = \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {b}{a+2b} \\
& \left( \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {a^2}{a^2+2ab} \right) \left( \sum_{cyc} a^2+2ab \right) \geq \left( \sum_{cyc} a \right)^2. \\
\Rightarrow \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {a}{a+2b} \geq 1, 
\sum_{cyc} \dfrac {2b}{a+2b} \leq 2. \\
\therefore \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {b}{a+2b} \leq 1. \blacksquare \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac {x}{x^4+2x} \leq 1. \\
\ \\
& x^4+1+1+1 \geq 4x. \text{ (AM-GM)} \\
\Rightarrow \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2x}{2x^4+x^4+3} \leq \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2x}{2x^4+4x} \leq 1. \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{2x}{3x^4+3} \leq 1, \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{x}{x^4+1} \leq \dfrac 3 2. \blacksquare
\end{align}

I came up with this idea while I was backtracking from this inequality, and found inevitable to use the substitution: $xyz=1$ to $x=a/b, y=b/c, z=c/a.$

See this post for a proof. Here is an alternative.
$$\sum \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1} \leqslant 2 \overset{!}{\implies} \frac{x}{1+x^4} \leqslant \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1} \iff \frac{(3x^4+2x^3+4x^2+2x+3)(x-1)^2}{4(x^4+1)(x^4+x^2+1)} \geqslant 0$$
Which is true.
Note: $\sum\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}\leq 2 \leftrightarrow \sum \frac{1}{x^4+x^2+1} \geq 1$ . If we let $x^2 = \frac{bc}{a^2} , y^2 = \frac{ac}{b^2}, z^2 = \frac{ab}{c^2}$ then we need to prove $\sum \frac{a^4}{a^4+a^2bc+b^2c^2} \geq 1$
which holds because $\sum \frac{a^4}{a^4+a^2bc+b^2c^2} \geq \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{\sum a^4+abc\sum a+\sum a^2b^2} \geq 1$.

If $x_{max}=y_{max}=z_{max}=mean(x,y,z)$ then $\alpha =( x=y=z)$while $xyz=1$ then $\alpha^{3} = 1 =\alpha $ we can use this to find their minimum sum of a symmetric function
$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{1+x^4} \leq 3\cdot  \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha^4} \leq \frac{3}{2}$

This question has been asked and  answered 5 times, I think it should be closed

If you think so, vote to close - duplicate.
